# If cell 1 contains w cell 2 should equal x, if cell 1 contains y cell 2 should contain z

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make an automated character sheet for D&D and for the equipment I would like to set it up so if the list of equipment the character has contains any individual weapon, the stats for making attack with that weapon appear in the attacks section. I've been using a formula referencing a table of all the statistics of all weapons on another part of the same sheet, and I can make it work for no more than two weapons. This is the formula:

```
=IF(OR(M13=A115);B115;IF(M13=A116;B116))
```

M13 is the the list of equipment the character has

```
A115=Club
B115=1d4 BL
A116=Greatclub
b116=1d8 BL
```

Note that the first part of the `IF` function is an `OR` function and the second part is another `IF` function. I don't know if that means you can only have one `IF` and one `OR` function in the overall `IF` function, but it will not work if I try changing the second `IF` function to an `OR` function, giving me error 504 and if I try changing the `OR` function to an `IF` function I get `#VALUE`!

To put it in simpler terms if cell `C1=A1` D1 should equal B1. If `C1=A2` D1 should equal B2 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I see where your going with that IF formula (I think), but what I think you really want is a `=VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(M13, A115:B200, 2, false)
```

This will search the range A115:A200 for the value in M13. When it finds it, it will stick the value from the corresponding B row into the cell where this formula exists.